# django templates with-tag custom filter

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a `dict` of lists containing images. The key is the `id` of a `journey`. Now I want to get an image list based on the id so I wrote a filter:

```
@register.filter
def dict_value(dict, key):
    return dict.get(key)
```

Now I want to use this filter but how? This is what I did:

```
{% for journey in journeys %}
    ...
    {% with imagelist={{ images|dictvalue:{{journey.id}} }} %}
        {% if imagelist %}
        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="" style="height: 225px; width: 100%; display: block;" src="{{imagelist.0.url}}" data-holder-rendered="true">
        {% else %}
        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="" style="height: 225px; width: 100%; display: block;" src="https://via.placeholder.com/348x225.png" data-holder-rendered="true">
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

For testing, I want to display the first image if the list is not empty.

But I have a problem with the `with-tag`. How do I do it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a template filter, you do not need to use extra double curly brackets, you can write this as:

```
{% with imagelist=images|dictvalue:journey.id %}
```

That being said, it is normally *not* a good idea to implement business logic in the template. Normally one does this in the *view*.